# Schema name from SQLAlchemy database URI not reflected to metadata

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am constructing a SQLAlchemy database URI as follows inside of a `config.py` file:

```
    db_user = getenv("MYSQL_USER")
    db_password = getenv("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD")
    db_host = getenv("MYSQL_HOST")
    db_port = getenv("MYSQL_PORT")
    db_name = getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE")
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}?charset=utf8"
```

I then instantiate a metadata object in `backend.database.db` that the rest of the application imports whenever I want to interact with the DB via the metadata API:

```
engine = create_engine(Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
db_metadata = MetaData(bind=engine, reflect=True)
```

Both my engine and the resulting metadata object encode the proper DB URI, with the DB name included:

```
In [16]: db_metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[16]: MetaData(bind=Engine(mysql+pymysql://root:***@db:3306/main))

In [17]: engine                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[17]: Engine(mysql+pymysql://root:***@db:3306/main)
```

However, `db_metadata.schema` is `None`. This is a problem because downstream operations against `Table` class objects fail with the error `sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1046, 'No database selected')`.

I can *sort of* fix this by passing `schema="main"` to my invocation of `MetaData`:

```
db_metadata = MetaData(bind=engine, reflect=True, schema="main")
```

This get's me past the database not found error, but now my problem is that now when I look up `Table` objects from my metadata data I have to prefix them with `main`, which clutters the code up necessarily.

Seems like a quick change, but I've been reading through the SQLAlchemy docs and nothing is jumping out at me.[The documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html) says:

> *As referred above, the MetaData.schema parameter only refers to the default value that will be applied to the Table.schema parameter of an
>   incoming Table object. It does not refer to how the Table is
>   catalogued within the MetaData, which remains consistent vs. a
>   MetaData collection that does not define this parameter. The Table
>   within the MetaData will still be keyed based on its schema-qualified
>   name*

So I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't my invocation of MetaData automatically pick up the `main` schema?
2. Do I have to refer to indexed tables with the `schema.table` syntax, or is there an best-practices way to work only with table names?

Environment notes:

- MySQL version 8.0.20
- pymysql version 0.9.3
- Working in docker
- Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this out. Everything I've written about is properly handled, the issue was that I before the part where I tried to work with the metadata object for table updates, I had a function, `reset_db` that looked like this:

```
def reset_db():
    with db_session.connection() as conn:
        conn.execute("DROP DATABASE main;")
        conn.execute("CREATE DATABASE main;")
        db_session.commit()
    os.system("flask db upgrade")
```

I wasn't just clearing old data, but destroying the database and severing it's link with the ORM. Refactored this function as follows and now it works great:

```
def reset_db():
    db_metadata.drop_all()
    os.system("flask db upgrade")
```

The trick was to just work directly with the MetaData API that I thought was the source of my problem. This update to my test runner sped up the instantiation of my testing `BaseClass` considerably now that I'm not deleting and recreating the entire schema for each test run.